# Magento - Fatal error: spl_autoload() after adding to cart.

Tags: magento

I have just started experiencing this problem:
The site is fine until I add something to my cart at which point I start to receive the following error at the bottom of the page:

```
Fatal error: spl_autoload() [<a href=’function.spl-autoload’>function.spl-autoload</a>]: Class Mage could not be loaded in /blah/blah/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 244
```

The logged in user also gets logged out and they can not log back in again.

I’ve seen a couple of forum posts that talk about this possibly being a problem with memory but my hosts (Rackspace) assure me that the memory is fine (i’ve got 16GB of RAM).

So I’m stuck.

I don't think I've changed any code to cause this. But I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the Magento compiler turned on?  Is there any output in the logs under <magentoroot>/var/log/(system.log or exception.log)?

Comment: I have had this issue when I run out of disk space on my var/session or my var/cache.  I would check that your mounted system has enough disk space to write files, if that is the problem check the size of those directories so see if one of the two or both is taking up the space.  People who have the memory issue associated with this error get it because they usually mount a tmpfs to those locations.  Is this the same in your case?

Comment: Ok So looking at the logs I see this:ERR (3): Warning: session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Node no longer exists  in /blah/blah/blah/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 115. Does that give anyone a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So it appears that I am storing SimpleXml Objects in the session. It seems that this is a no no...

I have removed that code and all is working ok.

I still don't know why it works fine on my development server though but at least it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the sessions in `var/session/` and the problem was solved and it's working fine.